# Set size of ticks in all subplots

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a plt.figure(...) with several subplots, my code looks essentially like this:

```
num_plots = 2

my_dpi = 96 
fig_size = (1440 / my_dpi, 900 / my_dpi)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=fig_size, dpi=my_dpi, frameon=False)

# Subplot 1
fig.add_subplot(num_plots, 1, 1)
# plot fancy stuff

# Subplot 2
fig.add_subplot(num_plots, 1, 2)
# plot fancy stuff
```

What I would love to have is something like

```
fig.get_all_subplots.xtick(size='small')
```

Thank you for your support!

EDIT:

I think it should rather be something like *plt.get_all_subplots* instead of *fig.get_all_subplots*

Comment: Do you want to change the size of all the ticks in every figure generated in your script or do you only want to do it for one specific figure?

Comment: I want to change the ticks in all subplots of one specific figure in my script (at the moment it is the only one I have)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There a two things you can do here. If you want to change the tick size for all figures in the script you are running, you need to add the following at the top of your code:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rc('xtick', labelsize=20) 
matplotlib.rc('ytick', labelsize=20)
```

This will be sufficient for your current code as there is only one plot. However if you were to have more than one plot but only wanted to change the size of the ticks for a specific figure, then you could use `plt.tick_params`, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Temperature')
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=22)
```